# Python Script Not Finding String that is Clearly Present in a file

Tags: python, csv, tcp

I am attempting to analyze a csv file contaning a TCP stack trace.  I'm checking conditionally if a line of the file contains a certain string, then adding it to the dictionary.

The strings I'm looking for are:

```
[SYN]
[SYN, ACK]
```

I have checked the file multiple times.  Python can find the first string no problem, but cannot find the second.  Here's the code that checks:

```
#variable declaration
synString = '[SYN]'
ackString = '[SYN, ACK]'

#some code
#iterate through csv:
with open('EECS325Hw3Lab3', newline = '') as captureFile:
captureReader = csv.reader(captureFile, delimiter=' ')
for row in captureReader:

#code that doesn't work.
if synString in row or ackString in row:
        serverDict[currentServer].append(row)
```

And I know this doesn't work because when I print serverDict, I only see the [SYN] expression.  What is happening here?

Comment: Are you sure there's a space after the comma in the file?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the file contents?

Comment: You haven't indented the body of the `for` loop.

Comment: Can you edit your code to validate where all the appropriate indentations are? and as mentioned a small sample of the file would help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read it a with a `csv.reader` each row is a list of strings, and  'SYN' and 'ACK' will be consecutive elements of the list.  Just use open.

```
for line in open(captureFile):
   if synString in line or ackString in line:
        serverDict[currentServer].append(line)
```

Each row will be a string, as you want it to be.  You may want to strip the newlines, though.